# webrtc mips build: why rtc_executable build generate ELF 32-bit LSB share object instead of ELF 32-bit LSB executable

Tags: webrtc, mips

I tried to cross compile webrtc for mipsel:

1)`gn gen out/mips --args=target_os=”linux” target_cpu=”mipesel”`

2)`ninja -C out/mips`
Build succeeded, and I wan to run some example demo codes such as `example/peerconnection/server`, the artifact was generated as `peerconnection_server` under `out/mips`. When I ran

3)`file peerconnection_server`

it shows
`out/mips/peerconnection_server: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped`

My question is: How can I config the gn build system, so the generated `peerconnection_server` type is `ELF 32-bit LSB executable` instead of `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object` above?

Note: I also tried the arm build, the type is `ELF 32-bit LSB executable` indeed.